# YAML Error starting API: Location '???' must end with '*/'

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to load configuration files located within the **src/main/resources/properties** folder. This is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

To load these files, I'm using the following VM arguments:

```
-Dconfig=classpath://properties/xfb.common.properties;classpath://properties/cfb.cm.properties
-Dspring.profiles.active=classpath://properties/xfb.common.properties;classpath://properties/cfb.cm.properties
```

However, when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
10:54:59.608 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location 'file:./config/*/application-classpath://properties/xfb.common.properties;classpath://properties/xfb.cm.properties.yaml' must end with '*/'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.validatePattern(LocationResourceLoader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.LocationResourceLoader.getResources(LocationResourceLoader.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolvePattern(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolveProfileSpecific(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$2(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:116)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at api_module.ApiModule.main(ApiModule.java:52)
```

I'm using the following versions:

- Spring boot: 2.7.0
- Gradle: 7.4.2
- Kotlin: 1.5.3
- Groovy: 3.0.9
- Ant: 1.10.11
- JDK: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_271
- OS: Windows 10.0 amd64

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring.profiles.active` VM argument should contain a comma separated list of Spring profiles you want to use. For example, if you want to use a "dev" and "customprofile2" profile, you can pass it like:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,customprofile2
```

What happens then is that Spring will load profile-specific configuration files as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific). One location where Spring will look for configuration files is within the `./config/` directory, such as `./config/application-{profile}.yaml`. In my example that would be `./config/application-dev.yml` and `./config/application-customprofile2.yml`.

Now, in your case you're using the `spring.profiles.active` VM argument to pass a list of files. By doing so, Spring will look for a file called `./config/application-classpath://properties/xfb.common.properties;classpath://properties/xfb.cm.properties.yaml`. Since this is not a valid file, it throws an error.

If you want to load these properties files, you can use the `--spring.config.location` argument. For example:

```
--spring.config.location=classpath:/properties/xfb.common.properties,classpath:/properties/xfb.cm.properties
```

Make sure to use a comma to separate the files, and to replace `classpath://` by `classpath:/`.

There are various other ways of loading externalized configuration files. To check out what options there are, check [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).